# Editing multiple dictionaries with a single function:

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have 3 empty dictionaries:

```
dic1 = {}
dic2 = {}
dic3 = {}
```

And I want to add to these dictionaries all at once, using a function. What is the simplest way to do this, so far I have:

```
def fillDics(x):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, x):
            if count==0:
                    dic1[legendaryfn[count]] = 0
                    dic1[legendary[count]] = 1
                    count+=1

            if count==1:
                    dic2[legendaryfn[count]] = 0
                    dic2[legendary[count]] = 1
                    count+=1
```

Et cetera, this seems hugely inefficient. What am I missing? I'm pretty new to programming so I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: What's `i` in `for i in range(0, x)`? What happens if count > 1?

Comment: It's just iterating through the range.

Comment: Well, I know what `range()` does. I'm curious what you're planning to actually do with it, though. The resulting `i` value isn't used in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's accomplished like this.

```
for myDict in [dict1, dict1, dict3]:
  myDict[key] = value
```

Additionally, if the numeric values are meaningful to you you can add enumerate:

```
for idx, myDict in enumerate([dict1, dict2, dict3]):
  myDict['position'] = idx
```

Or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of dictionaries

```
def fillDics(x):
    for d in [dict1,dict2,dict3]:
        d[legendaryfn[count]] = 0
        d[legendary[count]] = 1
```